# Under what circumstances would you enable Windows as well as Anonymous authentication and impersonation?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis

I was doing some reading on IIS and ASP.NET authentication. I know that Windows/Forms/Anonymous authentication is a means to authenticate against the IIS. After authentication, the ASP.NET code runs under the account set in Application Pool.

I know that if we enable anonymous and impersonation then the ASP.NET code runs under that anonymous account.

Suppose we are using site which has only windows authentication enabled. 
Anonymous/Impersonation/Forms/etcetra are disabled. Then, I was just wondering under what circumstances would we need to enable the anonymous authentication and impersonation along with windows authentication?

Our site has Home page, About us and login page which are accessible for all. Then other pages are accessible once user is logged in. I also notice that the authentication can be changed for each page as well as web application in IIS (inetmgr). Please advice as to the implication of using IMPERSONATION.

Comment: If a part of your site can be accessed by anonymous then you need to turn it on. If the whole site is for authenticated users only, then you don't need.

Comment: We have 2 sites one with only windows authentication enabled and another with only forms authentication enabled. On each site, the Home page, About us and login page are accessible for all. Then other pages are accesible once user is logged in. Please advice on using of anonymous and impersonation..